# Program not showing all values in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, range

i have started learning python and i have problem.

I learn for loops and i am a little bit confused.

I tried this:

```py
for i in range(0,12,3):
    print(i)
```

Why program is not showing 12 value?
In other languages e.g java it works.

Anyone help?

Comment: Here is the documentation on [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range).

Comment: "In other languages e.g. java" there is no such thing as `range`. In your own words, what do you think `range(0, 12, 3)` means? Did you try reading the documentation? Also: does a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < 12; i += 3)` produce 12 values in those other languages? Why or why not?

Comment: i know how it works, i just wanted to get reputation points to be able to vote other answers and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper bound of range is non-inclusive. From the documentation:

> For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.

Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range).

---

Java's equivalent:

```
IntStream.range(0, 12 / 3).map(x -> x * 3).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Also does not include the upper bound. This will also print `0 3 6 9`, not `12`.

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound of a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is not included. The main advantage is that `range(len())` "just works" without having to subtract 1. For example:

```
>>> x = 'abcd'
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
...     print(i, x[i])
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```